# "Rebasing" EF migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sorry if this is already answered - saw nothing on searching.

I have a lot of EF migrations in my project, and to be honest it has become a bit of a mess. Between my git branching screwing up the migrations and what not, I'd like to see if there's a solution for this headache.

I want to "rebase" my migrations. Is this possible? Is there an "official" way to do it?

By rebase, I mean tell EF to look at my database schema as it is right now and create me a single migration that satisfies the schema.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Delete your existing migrations
2. Add-Migration SetupDatabaseFromScratch
3. Update-Database

Ah, almost forgot - **backup everything**

And you should truncate your _MigrationHistory table from tyour database if you want to keep your data. But once again, make backups before doing such thing.

Comment: When I apply the upate-database, it fails as a table (the first one in the migration) already exists.  I realize that it's trying to apply the update, as EF thinks the model and the DB are out of sync.  I just want to align my initial create model, with the DB (match the Hash Codes).  Is that possible?

Comment: You need to run update-database with -Script option, delete parts of the scripts where existing objects in your database is creating (but do not delete _migrationHistory part) and run this script against database.

Comment: @codputer There are a lot of information how to do it right, just google "how to code first migrations to existing database". This is a common problem.

Comment: Does rebasing the migrations cause the data to be dropped?